# Why can I use a Boolean as list index?

Tags: python, boolean

Can anyone help me understand below Python code?

```
In[41]: list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

In[42]: list_a[True]
Out[42]: 2

In[43]: list_a[False]
Out[43]: 1
```

Comment: In Python, `bool` is a sublcass of `int`; True and False are equal to the numbers 1 and 0 respectively, they just have a different string representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`True` is interpreted as 1 so `list_a[True]` is equivalent to `list_a[1]`
same for `list_a[False]` => `list_a[0]`

Comment: Ah, yes... I should have known that. Thank you!